# Как правильно импортировать динамическую библиотеку?

Tags: python, c++, pycharm, импорт, модули

Есть динамическая библиотека `my_lib.so`, полученная с помощью `Boost.Python`. В коде можно просто написать `import my_lib` и скрипт будет работать, однако `PyCharm` подчёркивает этот стэйтмент как ошибочный, мол, не может найти такой модуль. Из-за этого неправильно работает сортировка импортов. Как правильно импортировать такие модули?

Нашёл такое решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466708. Делаем одноименный питоновский файл, который вручную грузит библиотеку:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'my_lib.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

Но он устарел похоже, у меня не работает (эффект как от добавления пустого файла, видимо импортируется библиотека всё равно по приоритету). Хотя подчёркивания и нет.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось исправить добавлением в PATH пути к библиотеке как сказано тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/24197970